# Cannot read property 'done' of undefined due to switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function which gaining data by ajax. The problem is that construction switch causing this error:

> ```
> cannot read property 'done' of undefined
> ```

I don't know why...

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
function changeSelect(input,type)
{
 var out;
 switch(type)
 {
  case "sport" :  out=$.post("/ajax/ajax.php",{sport:input.value});
  case "competition" :out=$.post("/ajax/ajax.php",{competition.value});
 }
 out.done(function(data)
 {
  $("#output").html(data);
 });
}</script>
```

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Check if the type is equal to both case a switch have a default case if any else match and out is undefined.

Comment: You do need `break;` statements. But, the cause of your problem seems to be that your `type` is not `"sport"` or `"competition"` and thus `out` is never set.

Comment: What @jfriend00 said. Not sure what you expect us to do. Either change your code to work with `type` values that don't match or ensure that the value you pass is always one of the two. There is nothing really we can do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely cause of the error you are getting is that the value of `type` does not match either of your `case` statements.  Thus, `out` remains `undefined` and gives you the error you see.

In addition, you must use `break;` statements in case of your `case:` statements and `{competition.value}` is not valid ES5 Javascript.  Perhaps you want something like this:

```
function changeSelect(input, type) {
    var out;
    switch (type) {
        case "sport":
            out = $.post("/ajax/ajax.php", {sport: input.value});
            break;
        case "competition":
            out = $.post("/ajax/ajax.php", {sport: competition.value});
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (out) {
        out.done(function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly what you meant with your `{competition.value}`.  I guessed that maybe you wanted it to be `{sport: competition.value}`, but I don't see `competition` defined anywhere so I'm not really sure.

---

Or, perhaps remove some duplicate code and use this:

```
function changeSelect(input, type) {
    var val;
    switch (type) {
        case "sport":
            val = input.value;
            break;
        case "competition":
            val = competition.value;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (val) {
        $.post("/ajax/ajax.php", {sport: val}).then(function(data) {
            $("#output").html(data);
        });

    }
}
```